# bootstrap 2 collapse callback not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I wish to call an event once the bootstap 2.3 accordion/collapse javascript component occurs.

```
$('#accordion2').on('hidden', function () {
    console.log('hidden! ');
    //api.reinitialise();
});
```

I've tried calling the event for various items in the component but no luck in triggering the event in the callback.
Here is a simplified setup: http://bootply.com/85466

Comment: I forked your Bootply so that it's using 2.3: http://bootply.com/85521  -- `hidden` event seems to work fine.

Comment: Yeah senile moment on my part. I failed to realise the version of Boostrap was different to what I thought. The call back function has changed in the new release.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: I should have been using the below code since it is bootstrap3:

```
$('#accordion2').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
console.log('hidden! ');
//api.reinitialise();
});
```